# Multiple "where" conditions in Entity Framework 4 statements - Possible?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a funny feeling I'm approaching this problem wrongly. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a list of strings (`List<string>`) and I want to return all the rows from a table where  a particular field in that row matches one of the strings in the list. This is simple if I use a loop and execute one Linq statement per string. Of course, I want to avoid as many round-trips to the database as possible.

What sort of strategy would you recommend here? I'm comfortable using LINQ together with Entity Framework but I realise I might be limited by these particular technologies.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.

Comment: You can build up the query object all you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

```
List<string> yourList = ...;
var query = context.YourTable.Where(x => yourList.Contains(x.Foo));
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to this before. I tried exactly this, and I get the familiar **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.** message.

Comment: @CharlieSalts: Hmmm... `Contains(System.Object)`? Are you sure it is a list of strings and not a list of objects? Could you post your exact code?

Comment: Ah. *Now* it is. Before it was the contents of a ListBox. This works - thanks!

Comment: In my personal experience, EF's query provider is not as sophisticated as the L2S query provider. In practice, this means that EF requires you to materialize objects (such as Lists) before including them in queries. The QueryProvider is also much more restrictive about the types it will use in a query.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple `Where` calls would be analogous to an AND operation. What you want is an OR:

```
col.Where(w=>w==1 || w==2 || w==3)
```

Alternatively, mapping the SQL `IN` operator is the `Contains` method:

```
var vals=new[] {1,2,3};
var filteredcol=col.Where(w=>vals.Contains(w));
```

Answer (score 1):

For such kind of cases I use an Extension Method

```
public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
   if (source = null)
       throw new NullReferenceException("Source is Null");

   return list.Contains(source);
}
```

and call it as

```
c.Where(w=> w.In("a", "g", "f"))
```

Comment: That will work with LINQ2Objects but I doubt that will work in an EF query.